# find previous group when looping through a dataframe that is grouped

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `minute` dataframe that I grouped by `day`

```
day_grouped_df=minute_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))
```

Now I want to loop through each group and find the previous groups `date` inside the loop

```
for date, group_row in day_grouped_df:
    #here I want to get the last groups date
```

Here how can we fetch the previous group's date when looping through grouped rows? Is there any way to get the index like normal looping so that we can do (`index-1`)

Comment: at the end of the loop, you can assign the date to another variable like `date_prev = date` that will be usable at the next iteration?

Comment: @Ben.T yes am currently doing that. But was wondering if there is a better way like index-1